# How to resolve the issue if Spring Boot Application returns string value instead of JSP page

Tags: java, spring-boot-maven-plugin

This is my pom.xml file

pom.xml  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmz7z.png)

Application.properties File

```
#spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true

#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Registration</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    
    @GetMapping(path="/home")
    public String loginPage() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Application File

> @SpringBootApplication
>
> public class SpringJspDemoApplication {
>
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> {
> SpringApplication.run(SpringJspDemoApplication.class, args);
> }
>
> }

Output:

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W6Yh.png) this is the output I am getting a string value instead of jsp

Tried using Thymeleaf, tried to change @RestController-> @Controller, used @ComponentScan etc but issue not getting resolved.

Tried going through the solutions given on site but none of them are working for me, also they are quite older.

Project Structure :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPvJ0.png) tried to put home.jsp at /webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/ that is also not working.

what will be the possible solution on this, can anyone please guide on this?

Below is the code when I change @Controller to @RestController
[![

> Controller File

Blockquote

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZXny.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZXny.png)

And result is still

[image]

> I have checked the status under network tab which is 200 only
> [image]

Comment: replacing RestController with Controller should resolve this issue as SpringBoot  will then return a view (home.jsp), rather than a String. If it still doesn't work (you said you've already tried that)  , then you should describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Surely #spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true should be uncommented. Thymeleaf turns the strings returned from Controller into pages.

Comment: @dsp_user and John Williams Thank you for your quick reply but changing Controller to RestController not making any difference returning same result only that is string value even if comment or uncomment spring.thymeleaf.enabled.

Comment: @Shweta, the correct annotation in this case is Controller, not RestController.

Comment: @dsp_user Yah I am using Controller only for now, but nothing working

Comment: @Shweta,  you have to be more specific. "Nothing is working" doesn't explain much.

Comment: Hi @dsp_user I have already shared the entire project code on the post , just one difference is in controller file I am using Controller annotation(the correct one like you said before) now instead of RestController and still I am getting output as string value only that is 'home' and not the jsp page.

Comment: @Shweta, go to Developer tools (F12 in your browser) and check what is happening under the Network tab ( you should see something like localhost:8080/home and the corresponding http response status). That status should give you an idea whether there's something wrong.

Comment: @dsp_user so I checked the status under network tab as you suggested where status is 200 only, attached the screenshot in the post for same. kindly check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please Add @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.web"}) in your main application file

Comment: Thanks @ankit Yadav for your suggestion. Like you said I changed RestController to Controller, added EntityScan and ComponentScan in main application file now I am getting below exception   Whitelabel Error Page.This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.Circular view path [contact]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/contact] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!

Comment: ComponentScan is your controller package path mention clearly and check your path mapping is ok or not?application properties file and jsp file prefix path and jsp

Comment: package com.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class HomeController {

  @GetMapping("/home")
 public String showForm() {
   
     return "home";
 }
}

Comment: Thank you so much @ankit yadav for your guidance. Your given code is working fine. when I try to follow the same in my spring boot application it doesn't work but creating new dynamic web project and then adding spring dependencies resolving my issue.

Comment: Please upgrade my REPUTATION

Answer (score 0):

Replace @RestController   to @Controller like below

```
@Controller
```

public class LoginController {

```
@GetMapping(path="/home")
public String loginPage() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    return "home";
}
```

}